# How can I pass a value for multiple conditions depending on a string variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How iff how in when any string is there but we we want pass value for more 2 conduction.

```
var product = cbmproduct.Text.ToString();

int offer_id = product.ToUpper() == "BSN" ? 16 : product.ToUpper() == "MID" ? 17 :0;

List<Offer> offers = new List<Offer>();

Offer of = new Offer();

of.offer_id = offer_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching) and the [switch expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression).

```cs
namespace MyProgram;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetOfferId("BSN"));
        Console.WriteLine(GetOfferId("MID"));
        Console.WriteLine(GetOfferId("UNKNOWN"));
    }

    public static int GetOfferId(string someValue)
    {
        return someValue switch
        {
            "BSN" => 16,
            "MID" => 17,
            // more conditions here
            // ...
            // catch all, if none of the above has matched
            _ => -1
        };
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
16
17
-1
```